# SqlServer error installation on Ubuntu WSL?

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I´m using WSL Ubuntu in Windows 10.
My version is:

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS \n \l.
```

When I try to configure an Sql Server using the command

```
sudo /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr-setup
```

I receive this message:

```
sqlservr: Unable to open /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid: No such file or directory
```

This directory really does not exist in my computer.
Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It's [a reported bug on Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/1092), which is yet to be fixed.